# Solving $\frac{e^2M}{4\pi \epsilon_or^2}-\frac{mB}{r^{m+1}}=0$

Tags: polynomials

From Principles of Electronic Materials and Devices by S.O. Kasap, Fourth Edition,  example 1.3,

$\frac{e^2M}{4\pi \epsilon_or^2}-\frac{mB}{r^{m+1}}=0$

is solved by

$r=\left[\frac{4\pi \epsilon_oBm}{e^2M}\right]^{1/(m-1)}$

I fail to see how this is true, even by substitution I am not convinced that this holds.

I need help approaching this; how to derive the formula for $r$.

Comment: Are you sure tha the exponent in the answer is not $1/(m-2)$?

Comment: @Marco81 yes, I am sure. Thanks for taking a look at this :)

Comment: @Marco81 but there was a mistake in the equation which seems similar. It should be $\frac{B}{r^{m+1}}$ not $\frac{B}{r^{m}}$. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing $r\neq 0$, just multiply your equation by $r^{m+1}$ and get
$$
\cfrac{r^{m+1}}{r^2}\cfrac{e^2M}{4\pi\epsilon_0}=mB
$$

Now $r^{m+1}/r^2=r^{m-1}$ and
$$
r^{m-1}=\cfrac{4\pi\epsilon_0mB}{e^2M}
$$
So it is sufficient to take the $(m-1)$-root which is equivalent to use the exponent $1/(m-1)$, i.e.:

$$
r=\left(\cfrac{4\pi\epsilon_0mB}{e^2M}\right)^{1/(m-1)}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does this also prove that this is the only solution?

Comment: Since $r$ is a radius and thus real and $>0$ yes there is no other possible root.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{e^2M}{4\pi \epsilon_or^2}-\frac{mB}{r^{m+1}}=0$$

$$\frac{e^2M}{4\pi \epsilon_or^2}=\frac{Bm}{r^{m+1}}$$

$$\dfrac {r^{m+1}}{r^2}=r^{m-1}=\frac {4\pi \epsilon_oBm}{e^2M}$$

Can you see it now?